# How to pass the JQuery variable in JSON.stringify and receive in Server side?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, ajax

I have to pass the value in `JSON.stringify`and receive in Server side.

> **Note:** when I try to pass the value directly without using JQuery variable, It's working fine.

**Without Jquery variable**(it's working)

```
data: JSON.stringify({ "VendorID": "1106", "Date": "2016-12-30" }),
```

When I try to pass value through **JQuery variable**,

**Error message**

> it throws **internal server error**
>
> "Procedure or function 'FVendorAging' expects parameter '@Date', which was not supplied."

**converting date format from(dd-MM-yyyy) to (yyyy-MM-dd) using JQuery**

```
 if ($('#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDate').val() !== '') {
        dateAr = $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDate').val().split('-');
        var newDates = dateAr[2] + '-' + dateAr[1] + '-' + dateAr[0];
        alert('Date is not empty = ' + newDates);  //2017-07-11
    }
```

**Ajax code**

```
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        contentType:"application/json;charset=utf-8",
        url: "GPCreateCheque.aspx/BindData",
        //data:"{}",
        data: JSON.stringify({ "VendorID": +selecteVendorID, "Date": +newDates }),
        dataType:"json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert("success = " + data.d[0].DocumnetNo);
            for(var i=0;i<data.d.length;i++){
                $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1").append("<tr><td><input id=\"Checkbox" + i + "\" class=\"checkBoxClass\" type=\"checkbox\" /></td><td>" + data.d[i].DocumnetNo + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].Date + "</td><td class='ActualAmount' >" + data.d[i].OriginalAmount + "</td></tr>");
            }
        },
        error:function(result){
            alert("Error");
        }
    })
```

**C# code**

```
[WebMethod]
    public static UserDetails[] BindData(string VendorID,string Date)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        List<UserDetails> details = new List<UserDetails>();

        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GPMatajerAlSaudia"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("FVendorAging", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", "2017-07-11");
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VendorID", "1106");

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", Date);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VendorID", VendorID);

            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            foreach (DataRow drow in dt.Rows)
            {
                UserDetails user = new UserDetails();
                user.DocumnetNo = drow["DocumnetNo"].ToString();
                user.Date = drow["Date"].ToString();
                user.OriginalAmount = drow["OriginalAmount"].ToString();
                details.Add(user);
            }
        }
        return details.ToArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because you're prefixing the date variables with a `+`. This means that you're attempting to parse a date formatted string as a `Number()` - which will cause problems.

To fix the issue just remove the `+`. Also note that as you've specified the `contentType` as JSON you don't need to manually call `JSON.stringify` as jQuery will do that for you. Try this:

```
data: { 
  "VendorID": selecteVendorID, 
  "Date": newDates 
},
```

Comment: Genius, you are correct. It's working. But I cannot accept answer for another 9 min. I will accept answer later.